# Reset 1st Row with Add_row boutton

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the add button, the input will automatically be added next bellow row...if I want to reset 1st row after adding row bellow with the input value.How do I do this? if I input "a" in input box when I click add row button it will be appended but not reset 1st row

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "text":
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = table.rows[1].cells[1].querySelector("input").value;
        break;
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
        break;
      case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
  //clearForm();
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 1) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
  <table id="dataTable" width="550px" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Select </th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. I played with your snippet and it seems like it's not clearing the input for the first row? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish either, maybe more context would be nice. Redrawing the table each time is a cheap operation until you start to get massive amounts of rows or data, so that is an option. If that's not viable, then I would maybe work on identifying the rows with an attribute and not just the index to make this table more scalable. If you don't, it's going to be hard to keep up with after you add more and more functionality.

Comment: If you did either one of those, I believe that would work your issue out as a side effect.

Comment: I want to reset only 1st row with add row click

Answer (score 0):

The following resets the value of the first input when you add a new row.  I'm not super sure why you'd want this functionality.  It seems a little counter-intuitive for the end user, but nevertheless, here you go:

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "text":
        var myInput = table.rows[1].cells[1].querySelector("input");
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = myInput.value;
        myInput.value = "";
        break;
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
        break;
      case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
  //table.getElementsByTagName("td")[1].getElementsByTagName("input").value = "test";
  //console.log(table.getElementsByTagName("td")[1].getElementsByTagName("input").value);
  //clearForm();
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 1) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
  <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
  <table id="dataTable" width="550px" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Select </th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: @DebsishGhosh If you could upvote/mark as solution, that'd help a lot!  You're welcome.  The part I modified was `var myInput = table.rows[1].cells[1].querySelector("input");
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = myInput.value;
        myInput.value = "";`